# Product page tabs disappeared in admin after trying to add a new product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, catalog, product-attribute

I just followed instructions in [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module), in order to add a new product attribute. After that most of my product tabs disappeared.

[image]

Here are my final codes:

> /app/code/local/MyCompany/MultiSlider/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Setup.php

```
<?php
class MyCompany_MultiSlider_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{
    public function getDefaultEntities()
    {
        return array(
            'catalog_product' => array(
                'entity_model'      => 'catalog/product',
                'attribute_model'   => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
                'table'             => 'catalog/product',
                'attributes'        => array(
                            'myattribcode' => array(
                                'group'             => 'Group/Tab',
                                'label'             => 'My Attrib Label',
                                'type'              => 'int',
                                'input'             => 'boolean',
                                'default'           => '0',
                                'class'             => '',
                                'backend'           => '',
                                'frontend'          => '',
                                'source'            => '',
                                'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                                'visible'           => true,
                                'required'          => false,
                                'user_defined'      => false,
                                'searchable'        => false,
                                'filterable'        => false,
                                'comparable'        => false,
                                'visible_on_front'  => false,
                                'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                                'unique'            => false
                            ),

               )
        ),
             // define attributes for other model entities here
      );
    }
}
```

> /app/code/local/MyCompany/MultiSlider/sql/multislider_setup/mysql4-install-1.2.3.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->installEntities();
```

> /app/code/local/MyCompany/MultiSlider/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class MyCompany_MultiSlider_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

> /app/code/local/MyCompany/MultiSlider/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyCompany_MultiSlider>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </MyCompany_MultiSlider>
  </modules>
  <global>

    <helpers>
      <multislider>
        <class>MyCompany_MultiSlider_Helper</class>
      </multislider>
    </helpers>
    <models>
          <multislider>
              <class>MyCompany_MultiSlider_Model</class>
          </multislider>
    </models>

    <resources>

          <multislider_setup>
              <setup>
                  <module>MyCompany_MultiSlider</module>
                  <class>MyCompany_MultiSlider_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
              </setup>
              <connection>
                  <use>core_setup</use>
              </connection>
          </multislider_setup>

          <multislider_write>
              <connection>
                  <use>core_write</use>
              </connection>
          </multislider_write>

          <multislider_read>
              <connection>
                  <use>core_read</use>
              </connection>
          </multislider_read>

      </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

> As an example, Name attribute row in eav_attribute table:

```
# attribute_id, entity_type_id, attribute_code, attribute_model, backend_model, backend_type, backend_table, frontend_model, frontend_input, frontend_label, frontend_class, source_model, is_required, is_user_defined, default_value, is_unique, note

'71', '4', 'name', NULL, NULL, 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'text', 'Name', NULL, NULL, '1', '0', NULL, '0', NULL
```

> eav_attribute table

```
# attribute_group_id, attribute_set_id, attribute_group_name, sort_order, default_id
'1', '1', 'General', '1', '1'
'2', '2', 'General', '1', '1'
'3', '3', 'General', '10', '1'
'4', '3', 'General Information', '2', '0'
'5', '3', 'Display Settings', '20', '0'
'6', '3', 'Custom Design', '30', '0'
'7', '4', 'General', '1', '1'
'8', '4', 'Prices', '2', '0'
'9', '4', 'Meta Information', '3', '0'
'10', '4', 'Images', '4', '0'
'11', '4', 'Recurring Profile', '5', '0'
'12', '4', 'Design', '6', '0'
'13', '5', 'General', '1', '1'
'14', '6', 'General', '1', '1'
'15', '7', 'General', '1', '1'
'16', '8', 'General', '1', '1'
'17', '4', 'Gift Options', '7', '0'
'18', '4', 'Group/Tab', '8', '0'
```

Now the problem is, even if I disable this module (and reindex, logout, login, recache), the product page tabs still not showing and no attributes added. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: restore a backup and try again

Comment: @Jeroen That's not a solution

Comment: Did you take a look in the database eav_attribute if other attributes still exist and are linked? That's why you need to test on a development environment

Comment: Are attribute sets still complete?

Comment: @Jeroen Yes the set is complete. All product attributes are there, as an example, here is product name attribute:
# attribute_id, entity_type_id, attribute_code, attribute_model, backend_model, backend_type, backend_table, frontend_model, frontend_input, frontend_label, frontend_class, source_model, is_required, is_user_defined, default_value, is_unique, note
'71', '4', 'name', NULL, NULL, 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'text', 'Name', NULL, NULL, '1', '0', NULL, '0', NULL ... see the updated question

Comment: So, I had a weekend to think, how about attributesetgroups? eav_attribute_groups, all in tact and complete? or via Catalog / Attribute / Manage attribute sets

Comment: @Jeroen So I had a weekend to recover a new Magento backup :D. Anyway lets solve this. I just updated the question bt adding eav_attribute_groups table content.

Answer (score 3):

On that page you can see a section that says (in Step 4: Define your entities):

"From Magento 1.4, don’t forget to add these following lines. Between ‘table’ and ‘attributes’ elements. ;)

```
'additional_attribute_table' => 'catalog/eav_attribute',
'entity_attribute_collection' => 'catalog/product_attribute_collection',
```

Without that, the General, Meta, Images, ... Tabs will not showing up in the product edit page. "

If you hadn't allready fixed it via a backup you could have added those two lines below

`'table'             => 'catalog/product',`

And re-ran the script by updating the core_resourses table to the required version to make the script run again.