# Backend Product "General" tab disappearing

Tags: magento2, attribute-set, magento-2.1.2, product-tab

Disclaimer: I'm not having quite the same problem as [described here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60597/product-page-tabs-disappeared-in-admin-after-trying-to-add-a-new-product-attribu)

What I've done is add an **Attribute** using **Stores > Attributes > Product**. In there I entered a name, changed **Storefront Properties > Visible on Catalog Page ... > Yes** and saved the **Attribute**.

I then added edited the default **Attribute Set** in **Stores > Attributes > Attribute Set**, created a new **Attribute Group**, drag/drop the previously created **Attribute** and saved.

Now whenever I go to a **Product** page in the backend (edition/creation), the *General* tab is gone. The only way for me to see it is to delete the **Attribute Group**.

Has anyone already experienced this? If so, what's the procedure to follow?